# Undefined variable with custom made service provider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I was following a tutorial from [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/25) to pass data to partials.[Note: Using Laravel 5.3] I have done every step as in the video, but I'm getting undefined variable error in partial (_nav).I did went through all comment in video and some of them also had same problem but there wasn't any solution. Don't know what went wrong.Is this because I'm using Laravel 5.3 and tutorial was made on Laravel 5

Below is my code:
Added custom made service provider in `config/app.php`

```
App\Providers\ViewComposerServiceProvider::class,
```

Custom made service provider `ViewComposerServiceProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class ViewComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->composeNavigation();
    }
    public function register()
    {
    //
    }

    private function composeNavigation(){
        view()->composer('partials._nav','App\Http\Composers\NavigationComposer');
    }
}
```

`NavigationComposer.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Composers;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use App\Tour;
class NavigationComposer{

public function compose( View $view)
   {
       $view->with('latest',Tour::latest()->first());
   }
}
```

Partials code (`partials._nav`)

```
<li><a href="#">{{$latest->title}}</a></li>
```

Comment: Try to run `composer dumpauto` and `php artisan clear-compiled` commands.

Comment: Tried as per your instruction still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you were aware that tutorial video was made on Larave 5 and you are doing it in 5.3. And method mentioned or say practiced in video doesn't work [not complete] in laravel 5.3. You are right about creating custom Service Provider and class to handel the query request.

In your `ViewComposerServiceProvider.php` remove `composeNavigation()` mentod and add the following in `boot()` method

```
      View::composer(
        'partials/_nav', 'App\Http\Composers\NavigationComposer'
    );
```

And other code seems all fine.Here is the official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers)